# Security Issues with HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

Tags: php, security, http

I'm currently taking `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` and saving it to an image file. Are there any exploitable security issues that I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

The security implications are the same as with any other file upload mechanism. You might have semantic implications, as the POST body might not be raw data, e.g. if it is quoted-printable encoded or compressed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if my `POST` body looks like...

```
<?php

rmdir(__DIR__ . '/../');
```

...and I can access the file via a URL (only if your image extension is set to run PHP, not likely but possible), or you run it (accidentally `include` it, for example), you will be in trouble.

If you wanted to be *safe*, store the file above the document root and use an image processing library such as GD to write the image from string and save that output. If it's a malicious file, you should only end up with a garbage outputted image.

Comment: I don't think **an image** would `eval()` the POST body.

Comment: This will be an issue only if the file is interpreted by the webserver as a PHP script and actually passed to the PHP interpreter. HOWEVER, this is possible if the file is saved as `filename.php.jpg` AND apache is configured with the `MultiViews` option enabled.

Comment: How can the image be executed as php code when apache is configured correctly? Also: FGITW much?

Comment: @bsdnoobz An image would not, and I never said it would.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa There has been instances of open source software being broken into via things such as PHP files that output an image's blog using `include` instead of `readfile()`. What does your last sentence imply?

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa alex is correct (+1), what he describes is known as a LFI Vulnerability http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Local_File_Inclusion . And they are shockingly common in PHP projects. If you had one in your code and this sort of image file was present, an attacker could execute it as PHP. Like many things in security, it all gets interesting when you get two or more different vuls to party together.

Comment: @Cheekysoft Thanks for coming along with the link :)